# Simple If Then VB Script for ArcGIS Field Calculator

Tags: arcmap, field-calculator, vbscript

I have a very simple If Then statement for the ArcGIS Field Calculator that is not working and I have no idea why. Could someone tell me where I went wrong?

```
...
Dim x as Integer
IF [QMD9] > 20 THEN
   x = 1
ELSE
  x = 0
ENDIF - 'thought this was it and changed to End If. Still doesn't work
...
```

[image: field calculator]
[image: error message]

Comment: [class] is a short integer field.

Answer (score 1):

I removed the Dim and it worked. Not required. Confused with VBA.

Comment: I think the Dim was needed (or at last accepted) in earlier version of ArcMap, now it should be ommited